# In my makefile, $(PWD) not get current work directory, but get empty

Tags: makefile

i have a statement $(PWD) in my Makefile, but unexpectly, i got empty value of it.

```
    @echo 'pwd:'
    echo $(PWD)
```

but just get:

```
pwd:
```

Comment: I don't reproduce. `$(PWD)` is looking for a Make variable, and there is one of that name here (initialized from the similarly named environment variable). If you want it to be interpreted by the shell, you should quote it, so `$$(PWD)` but that would try to execute the `PWD`  and there is none here, so you'd need `$$PWD` for the shell variable or `$$(pwd)` to execute the `pwd` command in the shell. (That's for a Unix environment, hopefully if you are using something else that's enough to make you find your issue yourself).